# What is the exact definition of 'consistent field theory'?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

When reading the [definition of the Haag-Lopuszanski-Sohnius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%E2%80%93Lopuszanski%E2%80%93Sohnius_theorem), it mentions a 'consistent 4-dimensional quantum field theory':

> the Haag–Lopuszanski–Sohnius theorem shows that the possible
>   symmetries of a consistent 4-dimensional quantum field theory do not
>   only consist of internal symmetries and Poincaré symmetry, but can
>   also include supersymmetry as a nontrivial extension of the Poincaré
>   algebra.

What is the exact mathematical definition of *consistent quantum field theory* in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The paper referenced, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321375902795
states the assumptions on the genrator of a symmetry or supersymmetry in Section 2: 
(i) it commutes with the S-matrix; 
(ii) it acts additively on the states of several incoming particles.

Consistent refers to interpreting these assumptions in the frame of Haag's [local quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_quantum_field_theory) (as is said explicitly in the third paragraph of the section). The latter is known to be mathematically consistent - there are many interacting examples in 2 and 3 space-time dimensions (though, due to technical difficulties, so far none in four).

Comment: Sir, could you please write those part of the link that is concerned here? Otherwise the answer would become invalid once the link becomes dead.

Comment: @user36790: My link is the official publication link and is likely to be valid longer than the link in the PO's question. - Apart from that I wrote already the essential part of the definition - namely Haag's local quantum theory.

Comment: I only have access to the abstract, cannot read section 2

Comment: @diffeomorphism: I added a bit more detail; but to understand the full argument you should read the paper.